# word addin tool tips and balloons

Tags: winforms, vsto, ms-office

Do you know of a way to show a tool tip ( or a balloon) similar to that, that appears in MS word 2007 and 2010 when you select a text and move you're mouse over it ( the one containing font options and other options) , from within an addin ?

Answer (score 0):

Not without a LOT of work.

Word doesn't source any events of the mouse moving. About the only thing you get is the selection changed and the docchanged events, and those aren't terribly useful.

You could hook into system wide mouse events via API stuff and monitor it.

Alternately, you could poll, say, every second or two, for the active selection location in the document and check your context from the selection, and then pop up your own tooltip window. Gotta be careful with polling though, or you could swamp the machine and introduce a drag on performance.

And finally, depending on what you need, you could use the AutoTextList field in Word. It is the only field type that has a "tool tip" argument. Whatever you enter for that argument is displayed as a tooltip by Word whenever you hover over that field.